# Image cannot be displayed using imshow

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Input Image is

[image: Input]

i was trying to apply hilbert transform on images. My aim is to detect the edges in the image. I cannot display the image. My code is as follows:

```
clear; close all;
I = imread('sub.png');
ty    = rgb2gray(I);
figure; imshow(ty)
ty= double(ty);
ty = adapthisteq(ty);
filtSize = 10; 
H1 = fspecial('gaussian',[filtSize,filtSize],2);
H2 = fspecial('gaussian',[filtSize,filtSize],2);
H = H2-H1;
Hedge = imag(hilbert(H));
Iodd = sqrt(imfilter(ty,Hedge).^2 + imfilter(ty,Hedge.').^2);
figure; imshow(Iodd)
G = log(Iodd);
G = max(G(:)) - G;
figure,
imshow(G), colorbar
```

output is:
[image: output]

2) Is there any difference between the result of gradient of an image and hilbert transform?

Comment: checkout your edge-detecting algorithm, it seems `Iodd` is always 0.

Comment: no .i dont think so.can you correct it

Comment: @abcd Yes, 'Iodd' is allways 0.

Comment: sorry it was a mistake.i corrected it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has absolutely nothing to do with the output.

In your code `Iodd` has all zero values. that means that `log(Iodd)` is undefined, thus `NaN`. `G` is just `NaN`.

And that is, unfortunately, because you have little idea of what you are doing!

First of all, `adapthisteq` needs a double image, but WAIT! an image whos data is of type double and a double image is not exactly the same. A double image is an image from 0-1 and an image whos data is double is just a memory thing. You want the 0-1. Therefore you dont want `ty= double(ty);`, you want `ty= im2double(ty);`. Check the difference of the two by adding a `imshow(ty)` just after `adapthisteq`.

And then your next part of the code. You do some fancy stuff! `hilbert`, `imag`, kernels, ... nice. Unfortunately , again, you are making a big mistake!

I suggest you have a closer look to this piece of code:

```
H1 = fspecial('gaussian',[filtSize,filtSize],2);
H2 = fspecial('gaussian',[filtSize,filtSize],2);
H = H2-H1;
```

If you look closely you will realize quite soon that you are creating 2 identical kernels and the subtracting them. Guess what `H` has as value.

You are filtering an image with a kernel that is all zeros. And then taking the logarithm!!!!

Comment: @abcd do not change the quesion now. Leave it as it was before and open a new one

Answer (score 0):

You see a black image, because all the values in it are very close to 0, or maybe even negative. To see something, you need to re-scale the values.

Based on the errors you are getting, there must be NaNs in your image. Try doing `G(isnan(G)) = 0;` before displaying it.

What is `min(G(:))`?  What is `max(G(:))`? What do you expect the range to be?

Comment: Error using imageDisplayValidateParams
Expected input number 2, [LOW HIGH], to be non-NaN.

Error in images.internal.checkDisplayRange (line 10)
validateattributes(display_range, {'numeric'},...

Error in images.internal.imageDisplayValidateParams (line 55)
common_args.DisplayRange = images.internal.checkDisplayRange(common_args.DisplayRange,mfilename);

Error in images.internal.imageDisplayParseInputs (line 78)
common_args = images.internal.imageDisplayValidateParams(common_args);

Error in imshow (line 223)
  [common_args,specific_args] = ...

Error in test (line 17)
imshow(G,[])

Comment: Sounds like an old version of MATLAB. Try `imshow(G, [min(G(:)), max(G(:))]);`

Comment: Error using imageDisplayValidateParams Expected input number 2, [LOW HIGH], to be non-NaN.Error in mages.internal.checkDisplayRange (line 10)
validateattributes(display_range, {'numeric'},
Error in images.internal.imageDisplayValidateParams (line 55)
common_args.DisplayRange = images.internal.checkDisplayRange(common_args.DisplayRange,mfilename);
Error in images.internal.imageDisplayParseInputs (line 78)
common_args =images.internal.imageDisplayValidateParams(common_args);
Error in imshow (line 223)  [common_args,specific_args] = ...

Error in test (line 17)imshow(G, [min(G(:)), max(G(:))]);

Comment: i'm using matlab2015 a.recently i installed matlab 7 too.is there any prob?

Comment: Actually, the problem has nothing to do with `imshow`

Comment: @AnderBiguri i edited the question.please dont downvote my question.i'm a beginner